# How to print a div content with jquery? (Make sure Printed content will be in colored form.)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to print a div element. I have a function that prints a div. But I want to print  a div content with css.

```
function printDiv() {
        var divContents = document.getElementById("mymodelid").innerHTML;
        var a = window.open('', '', 'height=600, width=700');
        a.document.write('<html>');
        a.document.write(divContents);
        a.document.write('</body></html>');
        a.document.close();
        a.print();

    }
```

Comment: do you want to write an html with css ?with css you can only give style to your element

Comment: Any way I suggest you to use document.createElement('tag name') to create your element and then if you like to style it there is another question

Answer (score 1):

This code will help you to print a div. But if you want to print it with CSS, you must use @media rules in CSS.

```
function printDiv() 
{
  var divToPrint=document.getElementById('mymodelid');
  var newWin=window.open('','Print-Window');
  newWin.document.open();
  newWin.document.write('<html><body onload="window.print()">'+divToPrint.innerHTML+'</body></html>');
  newWin.document.close();
  setTimeout(function(){newWin.close();},10);

}
```

Use @media print in CSS file like below:

```
 @media print {
         .mymodelid {background-color:#FF00FF;}
      }
```

if it doesn't work, you should change your browser options and check the "Background graphics".

Answer (score 1):

As sajadre said, I would also suggest to use `createElement()`.

To change the font color, you could use the method `fontColor()` (be aware that it is deprecated):

```
function printDiv() {
  const el = document.createElement('div');
  el.innerHTML = 'Hello World';
  var divContents = el.innerHTML.fontcolor("red");        
  var a = window.open('', '', 'height=600, width=700');
  a.document.write('<html>');
  a.document.write(divContents);
  a.document.write('</body></html>');
  a.document.close();
  a.print();
}
```